# Construct more simple functions by restricting the domain

Tags: functions, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I need a function that has the same values as

$f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cdot\sin\left(x^2\right)$

between $x=0$ and the following root of $f(x)$ at $x > 0$. At any other point, the function may differ from f (the reason I need this function is that I need to get the area under $f$ between the roots, but the integral is too complicated, and the area's value can not be directly approximated because my original f has more parameters, see "edit"). Here is the plot of f.

[image: function plot of f(x)]

The function f itself fulfills the wanted property (but its integral is really ugly).

So I was hoping that there was a function that has the same values in the range between the first two roots ($x=0$ and the smallest one with $x>0$), but may have a much more simple formula (and integral). The following image shows a red-colored function with (maybe) such a property:

[image]

The function is defined by having the same values between the first two roots and is - aside from that - point symmetric in every root. It looks much less complex, so I'd hope the formula to be much more simple for this function.

How can I construct a formula for the red-colored function? Also, is there maybe an even more simple function than the red one?

**Edit:**

As an additional info: The function of which I really need to get the area is

$f(x,a)=\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cdot\sin\left(3^{(4a-2)} x^2\right)$

where $0 \le a \le 1$. In my computer program, the parameter $a$ changes very, very often. I'd like to have an integral, since if $a$ changes, there should be done as few re-computations as possible.

Comment: Approach the Taylor expansion around $x=0$?  And if the red function is analytic, I doubt it is possible for it to be equal to the blue line over the desired interval, but rather arbitrarily close.

Comment: Perhaps you should include your original function $f$.

Comment: @SimpleArt You mean like at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Approximation_and_convergence ? That could work, though the derivations of f are also complicated (which would cost computational runtime). I'm still wondering if you can get an exact function for the specified area...

Comment: By the way, the second root is given as $\sqrt\pi$.

Comment: Yes, but don't take the derivatives.  Use the simpler expansion of $\sin$ and plug your arguments into it.

Comment: @SimpleArt you mean I should use the sigma-notation, but only the first few summands, and then do the integration on the polynomials?

Comment: Yes.  that is what I'm suggesting

Comment: Hm, maybe I should retract that idea.  At the moment, it seems that if I expand it out to the $x^7$th term, it doesn't even make it to $x=1$.

Comment: Perhaps you should rewrite everything using Euler's formula for complex trig functions.  The use of the exponential function may make the problem easier.

Comment: $$\int_0^{\sqrt\pi}f(x,a)dx=\frac1{2\beta}\Re\left(\int_0^{\pi}e^{iu}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}u^n\right)du \tag{$u=\beta x^2,\beta=3^{4a-2}$}$$

Comment: Oops, I mean to have $u/\beta$ in the summand.  >:( And it should be $\Im$, not $\Re$

Comment: Can I give up?  Perhaps Riemann summing is the easiest method.

Comment: @SimpleArt What should I do with this integral? should I try the first few polynomials and then integrate?

Comment: I had thought it might be possible to approximate by switching the order of the summand and the integral and then approximate the remaining integral, then evaluate the finite/approximate sum.  The solution to the integral, however, involved repeated integration by parts/hypergeometric series functions...

Answer (score 2):

Using the online WolframCloud, I came up with this code:

```
FourierSinSeries[Sin[t/2.]Sin[t^2], t, 5, FourierParameters-> {1,Sqrt[Pi]}]
```

which resulted in:

$$f(t)\approx 0.3825 \sin{\sqrt{\pi t}} - 0.285733 \sin{(2 \sqrt{\pi t})} + 
 0.0881179 \sin{(3 \sqrt{\pi t})}\\ - 0.0276503 \sin{(4 \sqrt{\pi t})} + 
 0.0109825 \sin{(5 \sqrt{\pi t})}$$

Their plot looks pretty much the same:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem any easier to integrate that though.

Comment: @SimpleArt Didn't notice the integration part :p I was wondering why such simple problem is left unanswered...

Comment: @polfosol Nonetheless, at least you found the function I was looking for. The integral looks a bit easier to me. Is this an approximation or exact?

Comment: @Johannes The fourier series has infinitely many terms (like the taylor series). By choosing enough terms, the error can be made as small as you desire. It seems these five terms are good enough and the error is negligible. And note that you will **never** be able to get an exact closed-form function other than the function itself! All you get is an approximation

Comment: polfosol: can you sketch a proof of the "never" part? This seems hard to believe.

Comment: @Johannes You want a function to be _exactly equal_ to $\sin(\frac{x}{2})\sin(x^2)$ in the interval of $[-\sqrt{\pi},\sqrt{\pi}]$. What could it be other than the function itself? Does it really need a proof? And by the way, the anti-derivative of $\sin\sqrt{t}$ is exact: $$\int \sin \left(a \sqrt{t}\right)  dt=\frac{2}{a^2}\left(\sin \left(a \sqrt{t}\right)-a \sqrt{t} \cos \left(a \sqrt{t}\right)\right)$$

Comment: @Johannes First see that the function you want to integrate is analytic.  Then see that if a function is analytic and equal to your function over an interval, it must be equal to that function everywhere.  Thus, you'd end up with your function again, which is not what you wanted.

Comment: @SimpleArt "see that if a function is analytic and equal to your function over an interval, it must be equal to that function everywhere": this does not seem to be true. Example: $f(x) = x^3$  with the interval [0,1]. $g(x) = |x^3|$ is another function (though, tbh, not that much different) that fulfills "the property". Then maybe we make a special rule that $|\cdot|$ is not allowed for such discussion. But then still, what you say is absolutely nontrivial to me. Maybe I need to open another question? :)

Comment: @Johannes Um, the difference between what I said and your example is that $|x^3|$ is not analytic... I would recommend looking up [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation)

Comment: @Johannes I think it's better for you to ask another question, making your point and addressing the comments in here. You might get some interesting ideas this way